# ajax multiple Values

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

i tryed to return multiple Values from an Ajax Call,

I would Like to retun Value a and value b in two separat Variables in my Ajax function.

Is it posible to do that? or could I use an Array? Or should i do for every Call a own Function?

My Function: "here i will do one ore more Database querys"

```
function rob_ajax_vorlage() {
global $wpdb;
$a = "100";
echo $a;
$b = "200"; //second value that doesen work jet
echo $b; //second value that doesen work jet
wp_die(); // just to be safe
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_rob_ajax_vorlage_approal_action', 'rob_ajax_vorlage' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_rob_ajax_vorlage_approal_action', 'rob_ajax_vorlage' );
```

And my Ajax call

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( '#rob-wp-ajax-vorlage-button' ).click( function() {
    var abc = $( '#abc' ).val();
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: { 'action': 'rob_ajax_vorlage_approal_action', 'abc': abc, }
    })
     .done(function( data ) {
            console.log('Successful AJAX Call! /// Return Data: ' + data);  
    .fail(function( data ) {
    console.log('Failed AJAX Call :( /// Return Data: ' + data);
  });
  });
  });
```

Im A Beginner so sorry if i asked something crazy.

so it would be grade if someone could help me to use return two values.

Thank you

Rob

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API instead of the old wp-admin AJAX?

Comment: The return data of your code will be `100200`. Is that not what you're getting? What is the message that you are getting in the log?

Comment: HI Tom, Now not jet. Do you have a Example for me? I would do get the retun in two variables not only in one?

Comment: Hi Jacob, Yes i Get this return. But i Want to have to seperat variables? so the i can work with Value a and value b in two variables,, Hope you understand what i like to do?

Comment: @Rob you need to return structured data, not a singular value, e.g. JSON. A quick google should lead to the instructions on building a primitive REST API endpoint, or a new question on this site. As for PDF creation, that's an entirely new question, and one that's not as easy as you might think ( and less of a WP question, more of a generic PHP/JS one too ). I'd also **strongly** suggest that you indent your code, it will eliminate entire classes of bugs, and make it easier to work with. Any half decent free editor will do the indenting for you automatically

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to give me the advise to work with JSON.

I Think i get it now.

Perhaps someone could look over it?

Here My Code

Button:

```
<div id="div3">
<button id="rob-wp-ajax-vorlage-button">ok</button>
</div>
```

My PHP Code

```
function load_my_ajax_vorlage()
{
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_js', plugins_url( 'ajax-vorlage-script.js',   __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), false, false );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_ajax_vorlage');
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_my_ajax_vorlage' );

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_localize_ajax');

function example_localize_ajax(){
wp_localize_script('jquery', 'ajax', array(
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('example_ajax_nonce'),
));
}


//Example AJAX Function
add_action('wp_ajax_example_function', 'example_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_example_function', 'example_function');
function example_function(){

$var1 = "value1";
$var2 = "value2";
echo json_encode(array($var1, $var2));

wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a  proper response:- https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
}
```

my JS

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>';
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( '#rob-wp-ajax-vorlage-button' ).click( function() {

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax.url,
 dateType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        nonce: ajax.nonce,
        action: 'example_function',
        data: {
            //firstname: 'fname',
            //lastname: 'lname'
        },
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log('Successful AJAX Call! /// Return Data: ' + response); 
        var result = $.parseJSON(response);     
        console.log('result0 ' + result[0]); 
        console.log('result1 ' + result[1]); 
         },
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
             console.log('ERROR AJAX Call! /// Return Data: ' + XMLHttpRequest);  
             },
    timeout: 60000
});

return false;
    }); 
 });
```

I Delete the scentence with the PDF i think you are right.

I will have a Look in REST API...

is this the right way?

Thx Rob